# LNK2019 - why unresolved external with template friend function

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I don't get this error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// LNK2019f.cpp
// LNK2019 expected
template<class T>
void f(T) {}

template<class T>
struct S {
   friend void f(T);
   // try the folowing line instead
   // friend void f<T>(T);
};

int main() {
   S<int> s;
   int a = 2;
   f(a);   // unresolved external
}
```

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(v=vs.80).aspx

Why does the error not show up if I comment out **S< int > s** ? I got that I need to declare the template argument list as well, but I don't see the connection between that templated structure and the **f(a)** call..

Another weird thing: if I comment out just the **f(a)** call (and I leave all the rest in place), it compiles again. I'm using MSVC2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because your friend declaration acts as a function declaration of another non-templated `f` function.

You have to declare it like this in order to tell the compiler that it is a template function:

```
    friend void f<T>(T);
```

Consider the following example:

```
template<class T>
struct S {
    friend void foo(int);
};

int main() {
    S<int> s;
    foo(42);
}
```

This will throw a linker error muttering about an unresolved external symbol `foo` here. In this case `foo` is declared but not defined through the friend declaration.

If we now comment out `S<int> s;` we now get not a linker but a compiler error: `'foo': identifier not found`, because `foo` has not been declared, as `S<int>` isnt compiled.

Comment: Added another detail: how come that if I delete the f(a) only, it compiles again?

Comment: @DavidKernin My guess is that your friend declaration acts as a functions declaration of another function `f` which hides your template function. Btw, I observed that `typename` isnt actually necessary. I will inspect this and edit accordingly

Comment: @DavidKernin Yep thats the reason, I will update my post

Comment: uhm, but even then if I instantiate the template.. there's no definition so it should throw. Right?

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with MSVC by the way... http://ideone.com/WldN4E this never fails in any case. And seems more logical, what do you think Paranaix?

Comment: @DavidKernin You might be right as I found this passage in the standart `The name of the friend is not found by unqualiﬁed lookup (3.4.1) or by qualiﬁed lookup (3.4.3)
until a matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope (either before or after the class deﬁnition
granting friendship)`. So while the friend declaration actually declares a function, the declared name is not consired during name lookup until it is declared in the enclosing namespace. So the compiler should find the templated f function.

Comment: MSVC has never been great at respecting standards.. it is sufficient for me. I'm awarding the points to you but please edit your answer with your recent findings so other people will benefit from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above the friend function f(T) needs to be template function. The compiler is expecting that when you instantiate f(T) in main.

Comment: The compiler should be able to deduce the type